# merging images with merge-images.js 1) does not place correctly and 2) gives "tainted" error on chrome

Tags: javascript, image, tile

I need a simple way to create larger images from tiles. I found merge-images library here ([merge-images](https://github.com/lukechilds/merge-images)) and on safari it displays images but not placed correctly. on chrome I just get error about a tainted canvases. If anyone can suggest solutions I would much appreciate it.

```js
mergeImages([
             { src: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/7/63/42.png', x: 0, y: 0 },
             { src: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/7/64/42.png', x: 256, y: 0 },
             { src: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/7/64/43.png', x: 254, y: 256 },
             { src: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/7/63/43.png', x: 0, y: 256 }
             ])
             .then(b64 => document.querySelector('img').src = b64);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/merge-images"></script>
<img crossOrigin="Anonymous"/></img>
```

Comment: Do you *need* to merge the images into 1 image, or would it be enough for your requirements to just display the images positioned correctly?  If so, you can just use CSS to do the same thing and never worry about browser incompatibilities (and it's very future-proof).

Comment: unfortunately I need them as one image

Comment: Okay, well you clearly can't use that library then.  You said it fails with Safari and Chrome and I tried it in IE as well and it also failed.  I suspect it's because the source images are coming from a different domain, and setting the crossOrigin attribute in the target image won't change that.  The only solution I can think of is to write a server-side library to download and merge the images for you.  Do you have any experience with ASP.Net or PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to convert the png images to base64 images then pass it to mergeImages.**

```
mergeImages([
             { src: base64 image, x: 0, y: 0 },
             { src: base64 image, x: 256, y: 0 },
             { src: base64 image, x: 254, y: 256 },
             { src: base64 image, x: 0, y: 256 }
             ])
             .then(b64 => document.querySelector('img').src = b64);
```

[Base64 Image Encoder](https://www.base64-image.de/) helps you to convert your images

Hope this works!